# VueJs Quasar dev server hot reload not working with script setup syntax

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, quasar-framework

We are building a SPA with VueJs, Quasar, Webpack and TypeScript.

We moved to using the `<script setup>` syntax a while ago.

Before that, the dev server didnt' make any problems. New components or changes to components were recognized immediately by the dev server, hot reload was working fine.

Using the new syntax now creates many problems. Whenever I write a new component, I have to manually restart the dev server to "see" my component in the browser. If I don't do that, I get the following warning in the browser console:

[image]

Sometimes this also happens when I add the refs/methods/ and so on to my components.

Did anyone else experience this as well?

Comment: Same problem as me. Did you solve it?

Comment: @jiniekim we solved it by switching to Quasar with Vite and completely discarded webpack. Now hot reload works as expected again.